# Optimal size of files for parallel reading

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, filesize, .net-4.8

I have a big file (around 8GB) with thousands of entries (an entry can be up to 1100 bytes).
I need to read each entry and thought about parallelizing this process by splitting the big file into multiple smaller files.
For reading the files I am using C# (`FileStream` object).
As far as I understood it makes sense that every smaller file has the same size.

The question is now what the optimal size for those smaller files is or if it even make a difference if they all are 20MB or 50MB large.

On my research I came up with different sizes 20MB, 8KB, 10MB or 8MB but always without further explanation.

### Update

The entries have a fixed size of bytes depending on the kind of entry which is described in the first 23 bytes of each.

So I'm reading the first 23 bytes, then i get the information of how many bytes i have to read until the entry ends. By this I managed to split the file by the kind of entry (34 files). 

Since not every file has the same size the different tasks for the files terminate at a different times.

Comment: What kind of optimization are we talking about? Speed? Memory? IO? What is your bottleneck?

Comment: Efficient parallelizing of Disc-IO may also depend on where the files are located ... so your task is not as trivial as it may seem. The "perfect" size _can_ also even depend on the bare metal (kind of disc, how it is formatted, file system, ...).

Comment: How are the entries separated inside the file? By new-line characters?

Comment: In general, IO does not benefit much from parallelization, and you do not need to separate a large file into multiple smaller, it is perfectly possible to read a single file concurrently with the correct configuration. But you need some way to know where each entry starts, you cannot just split a file at some arbitrary position. But the first thing you should do is *profile* so you have some idea of the actual bottlenecks.

Comment: Intuitively I would not expect a split file solution to be faster, but it would be interesting to hear what your actual findings are.

Comment: Hmm, so your question is not about how to optimize the reading of the big 8GB file, and splitting it to multiple smaller files. Apparently you are OK if this takes for ages. You are asking about the optimal size of these smaller files, in order to optimize the performance of subsequent processing of these files (the nature of the processing is not described). My answer to this question is: split the big file to a number of small files equal to the number of hardware storage devices you have, and then put each smaller file in a separate storage. If you have only one, then don't split the file.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias If i understand you correctly it means that i can only parallelise by the number of hardware storage devices the splitted files are read from?

Comment: Zyan from what small experience I have, modern SSD devices react positively to a little bit of parallelization (~2), while classic HDDs don't react well at all. If you try to parallelize those, the performance gets worse. So if your intended processing involves mostly I/O with the storage, don't expect massive performance improvements by parallelizing it.